# Has large scale mono fermentation of sugar beets been achieved?

Tags: environmental-engineering, biogas

Sugar beets are an interesting substrate for biogas production due to their high content of easily digested sugars and starches. However, they lack macronutrients to sustain the bacteria population. Reports of mono fermentation (no co-substrates) on a lab scale exist, the [longest running experiment I'm aware of](http://biogas-infoboard.de/pdf/Linke%20aus%205.%20Bio-Solar%20Biogas-Facht-3.pdf) ran for 240 days using an SBR for solids/bacteria retention (which somewhat alleviates the need for macronutrients).

Is there any plant digesting only sugar beets on a large scale (>10 t/d), where it is confrmed that no co-substrates are used? I want to stress confirmed, because the fact that a reference sheet does not mention a co substrate does not mean it's not there.

Comment: I love seeing activity in the EnvE tag but I'm not sure how useful questions like this are in the long run. Perhaps it has been achieved; then is the answer simply "yes?" Perhaps it has not been achieved; then how could we be certain? Even if someone is confident enough to answer purely on the basis of the absence of evidence, how could a future visitor be confident that answer remains correct? Or that it ever was? Very tricky.

Comment: Either the answer is "yes" (source) or no (credible) answer at all. I fail to see the problem with the latter.